# Meu botão de pesquisar em Angular JS, só recebe o parâmetro certo após ser acionado duas vezes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promises

Galera, vou resumir um pouco do meu problema, mas sem expôr demais o projeto, pois ele é de uso interno da empresa.. e não pode ser publicado.

Basicamente, eu tenho esse select chamado "Visão", onde através dele, posso alterar a tela e os parâmetros necessários pra exibição dos dados solicitados.

Por exemplo, nessa Visão "Minha Dependência", será mostrado os dados passando essa dependência de quem está logado como parâmetro, que nesse caso é a 8595.
[Tela 001 Minha Dependência](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1ZFw.png)

O que acontece? Quando mudo pra Visão "Outra Dependência", (que é a opção 4 no Switch case do meu Javascript) E clico em pesquisar, ela vai passar essa dependência que pesquisei como parâmetro pra todas as chamadas que eu fizer.
Só que notem na imagem 2, que mesmo eu pesquisando por 0203, ele ainda mantém a 8595 qu estava setada anteriormente. E o mais curioso é que se eu clicar em pesquisar de novo, mantendo a 0203 como parâmetro, aí sim ele passa o 0203 pras chamadas que eu preciso. Ou seja, ele só troca pela que eu preciso buscar após eu clicar em pesquisar duas vezes seguidas.
[Tela 002 Outra Dependência](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uHPF.png)

Alguém sabe uma forma de eu encerrar esse problema e passar a dependência digitada pesquisando apenas uma vez (que é o certo.. Kkkk)?

Ahh, esse projeto foi feito em Angular JS com requisições em java.
[Tela 003 - Código do Switch Javascript - Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qALOF.png)

Comment: cara, não é legal chamar partes de um script de ele/ela, por favor não faça isso mais.